Are there any ways to retrieve historical Google Street View image through API?
The Google Street View API only allows us to download the most recent street view images if we use coordinate information. I saw someone said you could get access to historical street view images if you know their pano ID, which is too much work for me to search it one by one. I wonder anyone knows faster and more straight ways to get historical google street view images, for example through picture taken time?

There is an existing feature request for the Street View Image API to provide historical panoramas at this link: https://issuetracker.google.com/35826204. You can check the issue as all
publicly available updates will be posted there. Feel free to leave comments
on that request as well for additional information.
